# Number of elements and number of different basis of $\mathbb F_5^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, statistics, field-theory

Let $\mathbb F:=\mathbb F_5$ the field with five elements.

(i) How many elements has $\mathbb F^3$?

(ii) How many different basis has $\mathbb F^3$?

My idea:

(i) $\mathbb F^3$ has $5^3$ elements.

(ii) The 1. basis vector must be different from the zero vector, so i've got $5^3-1$ possible choices for $v_1$.The 2. basis vector $v_2$ may not be linear combination $v_2=a\cdot v_1$ with $a \in \mathbb F$, so $5^3-5$ possible choices, and for $v_3$ i've got $5^3-5^2$ possible choices, so altogether $(5^3-1)(5^3-5)(5^3-5^2)$. But i'm unsure, whether i've counted to many? Do i have to divide my result through $n!$?

Comment: You do have to divide by $3!$ to account for order, yes, but otherwise correct.

Comment: Your answer is precisely correct, and @seaturtles points out that there are actually two concepts of *basis* of vector space: sometimes we mean the basis merely to be a *set*, in which his response is well-taken, sometimes we mean an ordered $n$-tuple, in which case you would not divide by $3!$.